# Verify ongamepadconnected/disconnected supported by looking for the GamepadEvent Existence

Tags: javascript, dom-events, gamepad, gamepad-api

So I just realized that the ongamepadconnected event returns a GamepadEvent object

Is it a good idea to just check for this object when trying to see if ongamepadconnected/disconnected is supported on the user's browser?

This way I, or any other developer can check if this event exists and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `'GamepadEvent' in window` is a viable feature test.

Comment: For some more background: I have documented the Gamepad API in an [article](https://web.dev/gamepad/).